# PHP Session Get Function Doesnt Work

Tags: php, session

I have a little problem, `login.php` registering myusername and mypassword.. and redirecting to `index.php?bolum=panel` (Control panel)

Login.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername; 
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
if(session_is_registered(myusername))
{
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('index.php?bolum=panel') </script>";
}
```

And Control Panel => panel.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?> <br/>
    Password: <?php echo $_SESSION['mypassword']; ?>
```

Why doesn't it work, I can't set myusername and mypassword in `panel.php`.

Comment: you might want to do var_dump($_SESSION) and make sure that your session_start() isn't within html code. It should be before the doctype

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for the redirect? Use [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) instead.

Comment: @AgentConundrum doesnt work. 
Class i do it but doesnt work.

Comment: don't use if(session_is_registered(myusername)), you can use something like this if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))

Comment: try `header('Location: index.php?bolum=panel');`

Answer (score 0):

`session_start` has to be called before any output is sent to the browser. This includes whitespace characters before the starting `<?php`. Remove them. Also, for development, activate error reporting:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: @Ryliatron move `session_start()` before the doctype

Comment: Deprecated: Function session_is_registered() is deprecated in /home/exeloria/public_html/pages/uyelik.php on line 141

Answer (score 0):

First of all - `login.php` :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername; 
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
   header('Location: index.php?bolum=panel');
}
?>
```

And how exactly do you get from **index.php?bolum=panel** to **panel.php**?

Comment: Now giving in panel.php =>
Notice: Undefined index myusername

Comment: I writed include("pages/panel.php"); (in index.php)

Comment: Ok, in **login.php** try changing:
`header('Location: index.php?bolum=panel');`
to
`header('Location: prdel.php?bolum=panel&sessionid='.session_id());`
And in **panel.php** replace
`<?php session_start(); ?>`
with
`<?php session_start();
echo "GET variables: "; var_dump($_GET); echo "<br>";
echo "This page sessionid(): ".session_id()."<br>---<br>";
?>`
And then compare the two session_ids. They _should_ be the same for it  to work.